# tips on imporiving on my set methods in second class

Tags: java

I have been working on my code the whole day and have changed it a bit. So my species class must add attributes for the name of the species, the population and the growth rate then it should all be added to an array list on the first class. However Im still confused on what to do on set methods with all the private variables given. Should I try and use switch statements or if/else statements to determine the newName, populationNumber, and growthNumber?

first class:

```
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.lang.Object;


public class Tester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    String name = "";
    int population=0;
    int growth =0;


        Species speciesObject = new Species(name,population,growth);


        System.out.println(speciesObject.getGrowthRate());

    ArrayList<Species> endangeredSpecies = new ArrayList <Species>();

    endangeredSpecies.add(speciesObject);

    //System.out.println(endangeredSpecies);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String menuChoice="";

    System.out.println("Please select an option");
    System.out.println("1) Florida Panther");
    System.out.println("2) Loggerhead Sea Turtle");
    System.out.println("3) Large Metal Mark Butterfly");
    System.out.println("4) Mississippi Gopher Frog");
    System.out.println("5) White River Spinedace");
    System.out.println("6) San Joaquin Kit Fox");
    System.out.println("7) Bald Eagle");
    System.out.println("8) Giant Panda");
    System.out.println("9) Grizzly Bear");


    menuChoice = scanner.next();
    if (menuChoice.equals("1"))
    {
         System.out.println ( "You picked Florida Panther" );
    }

    else if ((menuChoice.equals("2")))
    {

        System.out.println ( "You picked LoggerHead Sea Turtle" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("3")))
    {
         System.out.println ( "You picked Large MetalMark Butterfly" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("4")))
    {
         System.out.println ( "You picked Mississippi Gopher Frog" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("5")))
    {
         System.out.println ( "You picked White River Spinedace" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("6")))
    {
        System.out.println ( "You picked San Joaquin Kit Fox" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("7")))
    {
        System.out.println ( "You picked Bald Eagle" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("8")))
    {
        System.out.println ( "You picked Giant Panda" );
    }
    else if ((menuChoice.equals("9")))
    {
         System.out.println ( "You picked Grizzly Bear" );
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println ( "Invalid Selection" );
    }




}
```

}

second class:

```
 public class Species 
    {
//species names
private final String name1 = "Florida Panther ";
private final String name2 = "Loggerhead Turtle ";
private final String name3 = "Metalmark Butterfly ";
private final String name4 = "Mississippi Frog ";
private final String name5 = "White River Spinedace ";
private final String name6 = "San Joaquin Fox ";
private final String name7 = "Bald Eagle ";
private final String name8 = "Giant Panda";
private final String name9 = "Grizzly Bear";

//population constants
private final int FLORIDA_PANTHER_DOUBLE_POP = 120;
private final int LOGGERHEAD_TURTLE_DOUBLE_POP = 4200;
private final int METALMARK_BUTTERFLY_DOUBLE_POP = 150;
private final int MISS_FROG_DOUBLE_POP = 100;
private final int WHITE_RIVER_SPINEDACE_DOUBLE_POP = 50;
private final int SAN_JOAQUIN_FOX_DOUBLE_POP = 7000;
private final int BALD_EAGLE_DOUBLE_POP = 11000;
private final int GIANT_PANDA_DOUBLE_POP = 1000;
private final int GRIZZLY_BEAR_DOUBLE_POP = 500;


//constants for growth rate
private final double FLORIDA_PANTHER_DOUBLE_GRW = 5;
private final double LOGGERHEAD_TURTLE_DOUBLE_GRW = 24;
private final double METALMARK_BUTTERFLY_DOUBLE_GRW = 7;
private final double MISS_FROG_DOUBLE_GRW = 10;
private final double WHITE_RIVER_SPINEDACE_DOUBLE_GRW = 3.5;
private final double SAN_JOAQUIN_FOX_DOUBLE_GRW = 60;
private final double BALD_EAGLE_DOUBLE_GRW = 10;
private final double GIANT_PANDA_DOUBLE_GRW = 15;
private final double GRIZZLY_BEAR_DOUBLE_GRW = 32;


//class variables
String newName;
int populationNumber;
double growthNumber;

public Species()    
{
    this("", 0 , 0.0);
}
public Species(String name)
{
    this(name, 0 , 0.0);
}
public Species(String name, int pop, double growthRate)
{
    newName = name;
    populationNumber = pop;
    growthNumber = growthRate;
}



/*public void setSpeciesInfo(String name, int pop, double growthRate)
{
    newName=name;


    if (newName.equals(name1))
    {
        populationNumber= pop;
        growthNumber = growthRate;
    }
}*/

public void setName(String name)
{

}

public String getName()
{
    return newName;
}

public void setGrowthRate(double growthRate)
{

}

public double getGrowthRate()
{
    return growthNumber;
}

public void setPopulation(int population)
{

}

public int getPopulation()
{
    return populationNumber;
}

public boolean equals(Species obj)
{
    return (newName.equals(obj.newName)) &&
           (populationNumber == obj.populationNumber) &&
           (growthNumber == obj.growthNumber);
}

public String toString() 
{

            return newName + " (population of " + populationNumber + " with growth rate " +

                growthNumber + "%)";
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is a whole mess of redundancy.  How many times do you repeat the animals?  You should read up on the [*Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: that part that confuses me is that Im given many constants for the population and the population growth, Im not sure of how to store them in one variable to make them accessible in the first class and be able to store them in the arraylist. After thats done, Im guessing I can simply display an element per selection. All I need is a sense of direction

Comment: You should probably make a class `Animal` and add attributes for name, current population, growth rate, and so forth.  Then put all of them into a `List` or `Map` and conveniently iterate over them or look them up.

Comment: In your first class please don't use so much of ifelse statements,
why don't you use switch like this:

'switch(Integer.parseInt(menuChoice ))
        {
         case 1: System.out.println("one");
         break;
         
         case 2: System.out.println("two");
         break;
         
        }'
switch is easy to maintain and faster than if else